# Resuming from checkpoint with HuggingFace Trainer: does it matter what model/arguments the Trainer was instantiated with?

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-trainer

Instantiating a `Trainer` object from the `transformers` library [requires](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer.model) passing a model (or a `model_init` function that returns a model). After instantiating a `Trainer` with a model, if I [call](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer.train) `trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint="path/to/checkpoints")`, the docs say that "training will resume from the model/optimizer/scheduler states loaded here."

But what happens to the original model I passed to the `Trainer` constructor? Does it even matter what I pass?

Or am I misinterpreting the docs and the model passed to the constructor is what is trained, but the checkpoint just determines how many epochs are left etc.?

Similarly, if the checkpoint has a different set of `TrainingArguments` than are passed to the `Trainer` constructor, which has precedence? Do I even need to pass `TrainingArguments` to `Trainer` when resuming from checkpoint?